# SQLALchemy - populate relationship with rows from 2 fields in another table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following tables:

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'match'

    match_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    home_team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.team_id'))
    away_team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.team_id'))

    home_team = relationship('Team', foreign_keys=[home_team_id])
    away_team = relationship('Team', foreign_keys=[away_team_id])

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'

    team_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    matches = relationship(...)
```

How would I define the relationship in `Team` so that `team.matches` will pull every row from the `match` table if a team's `team_id` matches either `home_team_id` or `away_team_id`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The relationship needed to be:

```
matches = relationship(
    'Match', 
    primaryjoin='or_(
        Team.team_id == Match.home_team_id, Team.team_id == Match.away_team_id
    )'
)
```